# AWS Batch based on Triggering on event

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3

I have to run the aws based job based on the event for example if the file named as sample.txt is uploaded in the bucket then run the aws batch job.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

S3 trigger -> lambda -> aws batch

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so you'll get it as an answer...

You might be able to use the "Task Scheduler" built into windows.
You can access it by pressing windows key + r -> then type "sched"

Hope you can use it for something.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what i am looking for .I am trying to work on the following link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html Passing Event Information to an AWS Batch Target using the CloudWatch Events Input Transformer